# Best Solution for using shared folders in IIS Sites

Tags: iis, virtual-directory, iis-8.5, shared-directory, junction

I want to use the same folders (/images and /scripts) to be shared with 5 different web sites created in IIS 8.5.  What is the best solution? Virtual Directory? Virtual Application? Junctions? Symbolic Links?

Note: I noticed while using junction on a windows 8/ii7 machine, the changes i made to the scripts directory were not immediately reflected on all the sites... even after forcing a hard refresh in the client browser... I would have to restart the web application to see the change. Perhaps something to do with how server caching sees junction links?

BTW, I am running classic asp sites on a windows 2012r2 iis 8.5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Virtual directories are the path of least resistance for this, but you need to remember to configure your NTFS permissions so that all five sites can read (and write if need be) your static content.

The other alternative is to serve these resources from a separate website which is "cookieless":

> [How do I set up a cookie-less domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/1774/7610)

Comment: Thank you. However, the virtual path needs to be part of the site.

Comment: @Juan - you can do that with virtual directories, however you're correct that the second method would involve having to change the location of your static resources.